# Exporting or using adobe xd files for views in aspnet core

Tags: html, user-interface, bootstrap-4, adobe-xd

Hi I am new to frontend design.

I wanted to know, is there anyway to export adobe xd files to a responsive html code by just using xd files as views ?

I have designed a Html page but it is not responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can export Html from adobe xd file using plugin offered by adobe. i am attaching links which can give better understanding.
[Click Here](https://www.adobe.com/products/xd/learn/collaborate/developer-handoff/export-xd-to-html-css-plugins.html)

For more steps : [Click here](https://animaapp.medium.com/how-to-export-adobe-xd-to-html-87b3368315b7)

Answer (score 0):

Once you finish your AdobeXd design, you can use Desech Studio to import that file.

1. This will generate a decent html structure and will use css grids to position elements.
2. Then you will have to do some adjustments to match to your design file.
3. Then you can start working on the responsiveness which already has the modes in place and you can swap through them to apply style changes

My advice is to try to learn a bit of html/css to understand how the web stack works. This will clear out a lot of confusion. Check youtube, there are tons of html/css tutorials.